# Education begins at home

Tags: etymology

What (from where or whom) is the origin of the phrase, "Education begins at home?" I've tried a general "google" search but have not found any clear attribution yet.  It is a basic statement many folks make and generally take to be true, yet I don't know its source.  Someone out there does.

Comment: I'd have thought the "where" aspect (in terms of *language*) would be that it's effectively a variant of [*charity begins at home*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22charity+begins+at+home%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). The earliest instance of the "education" version I can find is [this from 1854](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Education+begins+at+home+under+the+paternal+roof%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but it's just a natural English sentence, so I doubt many people read it and thought *"Ah! That's a good slogan/maxim! I must pass it on!"*

Comment: Yeah, it's a riff on "charity begins at home".  But I doubt that you can find the guilty party who first spoke it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with FumbleFingers's observation in a comment above that "education begins at home" is so natural an observation that it would be somewhat surprising if no one had ever used it. The first match for the phrase that a Google Books search finds appears to be from "Visiting the Poor," published originally in a British publication, [*The Educational Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ow8LAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA295&dq=%22education+must+begin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HgoaVdTFAs-6ogSWkIDIDQ&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22education%20must%20begin%22&f=false) (May 1835), and excerpted with minor alterations in the United States in [*American Annals of Education and Instruction*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8dBMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA124&dq=%22education+must+begin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WwcaVcymJ4vgoASgkYCICg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22education%20must%20begin%22&f=false) (March 1836):

> Another important object of the visitor of the poor, will be the education of their children ; for it is to the want of this education, that half the misery of the poor may be ascribed ; but the visitor must sedulously labour to impress upon the minds of those he visits, that **education must begin at home**, that the parent must consider that moral training is the first step to all subsequent acquirement, and that physical education for the purposes of causing health and cheerfulness, is also necessary.

An even earlier version of the same idea appears in Vicesimus Knox, [*Liberal Education*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IblbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA12&dq=%22education+should+begin+even%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zA0aVdXbCtKsogSKxYCABA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22education%20should%20begin%20even%22&f=false), sixth edition (1784), though it is accompanied rather startlingly by an invitation for the man of the house to excuse himself from any responsibility in the matter at that stage:

> **Education should begin even in the nursery** ; and the mother and nurse are, in the first stage, the best instructors. The task of teaching an infant the alphabet, is too painful for a man of a very cultivated understanding.

In an associated footnote, Knox quotes Virgil on the importance of the task:

> Adeo in teneris consuescere multum est. VIRG. *Of so great consequence is it to habituate him in his tender years*."

So, depending on how you read Virgil's comment, assertions about the importance of getting a very early start on education goes back in Western thought more than 2000 years (Virgil died in 19 BC). The first edition of Knox's book appeared in 1781.

Twenty years before Knox, an English minister named John Brown was promoting the idea that a person's education should begin by the age of one. From John Brown, "[On the First Principles of Education](https://books.google.com/books?id=HCQHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22Work+of+Education+ought+to+be+begun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eBkaVf3pDpCuogT3x4KQBA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22Work%20of%20Education%20ought%20to%20be%20begun%22&f=false)," in Sermons on Various Subjects (1764):

> The important Question is, then, how soon **the Work of Education ought to be begun**, by instilling good habits and correcting bad ones.—To this I answer that it is of Consequence to begin it, at the very first Dawn of Reason, as soon as the Child can draw any Consequences in his Mind concerning things that relate most immediately to himself. ... These then are the Indications of the first Dawn of Reason ; and generally arise before a Child is one Year old ; in some, perhaps, much sooner. Now this early period precedes the Maturity of Reason by an Interval of many Years : But as this early Period is the Season when the first Habits take Place, it is undoubtedly the Time when the Work of Education should begin.

And of course, if the child is not yet one year old, any education that begins at that point must begin at home. It thus appears that the pedagogical foundation for the assertion that education must or should begin at home existed by the 1760s, if not much much sooner.

I'm not persuaded that "education begins at home" is an offshoot of the saying "charity begins at home," but it is certainly true that the two phrases are very similar in structure and that both appear together at least as early as 1859—in this quotation from "[Life in Arcadia](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ki0EAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA205&dq=%22education+like+charity%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AxsaVcLpL5btoAT4h4LQAQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBDge#v=onepage&q=%22education%20like%20charity%22&f=false)," in *Meliora*, volume 1 (1859):

> Chastity and modesty are virtues totally unknown to many of our rural poor. They scarcely recognise as failings sins which were 'not so much as named' among the Gentiles in the time when St. Paul rebuked the Corinthian church. **Education, like charity, must begin at home**.

The wording of the proverb "charity begins at home" may well have influenced the familiar form of the later expression, but the notion that a child's learning commences at an extremely early age was in place decades before anyone is known to have adopted the wording "education begins at home." For that reason, the similarity in wording seems to me more likely to be a result of a convergence in wording of a preexisting idea toward a familiar proverb than a spinoff of a new idea (and wording) from an existing truism.

Answer (score 0):

Then it is anonymous.If you have tried and found no answer, sometimes a statement just called as anonymous and in my opinion, those anonymous came from long ago or spread widely from a community without knowing who is the first speaker because the involved statement described the actual condition or daily life. Only famous people or well-known people's quotes/statements are recorded officially. Those are just my thought.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably like trying to find out who first said "Happy birthday".